# Bind Angular 2 variable to css pseudo-class content: attr() expression

Tags: css, angularjs, angular

I wanted to compare performance of rendering Angular 2 variable binding `[innerText]`/`{{}}` with binding variable as content of pseudo-class(because methods above forces element re rendering)

However, I struggle trying to make angular markup work with css.

That works

**CSS:**

```
.my-el:after {
    content: attr(my-attr);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="my-el" my-attr="text"></div>
```

But after change it to `my-attr="{{myVar}}"` Angular throws error:

```
browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: Template parse errors(...)
```

So I red that I should use `attr.my-attr="{{myVar}}"`

But after changing CSS to

```
.my-el:after {
    content: attr(attr.my-attr);
}
```

it doesn't work (I guess dot isn't valid symbol here?).

I know that all above may have not much sense, however I'm finding it as interesting problem which I can't solve so far.

Any ideas how to make these two work together? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to bind your value with the following way

```
<div class="my-el" [attr.my-attr]="myVar"></div>
```

This way angular will attach the `myVar` contents to the `my-attr` attribute

If you need to prepend it with `data-` use

```
<div class="my-el" [attr.data-my-attr]="myVar"></div>
```

Then you can access the value from your css with
`attr(my-attr)` or `attr(data-my-attr)`